# Flash does not activate window where I mark code

Tags: adobe-flash

In Flash CS6 when I mark code in one window, Flash does not activate that window. This means that no shortcuts are working for that window (save, copy, paste, etc.).

Are other users having that problem? And what are you doing about it?

Comment: I have this problem, too. In Flash CS6 I have 2 windows open side by side. One is the .fla Project and one is .as code. Now, when the .fla window is active I'm able to select code in the .as window just by clicking and dragging. Once the cursor is active in that window I can type and change code. However, judging from the window tab Flash is NOT regarding this window as active. Hence, no shortcuts and pasting results in a new text field inside the .fla window! Horrible! Any thoughts on this?